# Get specific value from Array Object in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

i want to get value of transaction id from this array.

Here is my array::

```
["{
transaction_id:1894934,
 pin:0534552925794805, 
serial:20236031783146920986
}",
 "{transaction_id:1894935,
 pin:0665208961850777,
 serial:20236031783146920987}"]
```

How can i get value of transaction id from this ??
It seems like objects in array and my values are stored in this format so, how can i retrieve particular value?

Comment: your inner elements appear to be in (an approximation to) JSON format - the Apple libraries include functions for decoding those.

Comment: Shouldn’t we expect to see some effort from OP, some code that shows that some effort was made to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty extraordinary format, an array of pseudo JSON strings. Pseudo, because they are not valid, the keys must be wrapped in double quotes.

A possible solution is to extract the values for `transaction_id` with `Scanner`

```
let array = ["{transaction_id:1894934,pin:0534552925794805,serial:20236031783146920986}","{transaction_id:1894935,pin:0665208961850777,serial:20236031783146920987}"]

let identifiers = array.compactMap{ string -> Int? in
    let scanner = Scanner(string: string)
    var value = 0
    guard scanner.scanCharacters(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted, into: nil),
        scanner.scanInt(&value) else { return nil }
    return value
}

print(identifiers)
```

To convert the string into a dictionary use Regular Expression

```
let transactions = array.map{ string -> [String:String] in
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\w+):(\\d+)")
    var result = [String:String]()
    let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
    for match in matches {
        let keyRange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: string)!
        let valueRange = Range(match.range(at: 2), in: string)!
        result[String(string[keyRange])] = String(string[valueRange])
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: thanks this will work for transaction id only how i print same for pin and serial?? @vadian

Comment: Actually just add a loop but this way doesn't work for the `serial` value because it doesn't fit in an `Int64`.